# What are the equations on this Apollo commemorative coin?

Tags: classical-mechanics, rocket-science

[Someone I follow on Twitter](https://twitter.com/settern/status/817948129781747717) found a commemorative coin given to her grandfather for his work on Apollo 11. It appears that these coins were given to various technicians and engineers at NASA and various Apollo contractors. The reverse of the coin includes five equations related to the mission. Here's a slightly clearer image than hers:

[image: Five physics equations, starting with F=Ma, many with symbols that are difficult to make out]

The first equation, F=Ma, is of course Newton's Second Law. What are the others? What is their significance to Apollo and spaceflight?

Comment: Lots of $\Delta $ s, I am sure someone will tell you them all, but they seem to me to be engineering based, the second could be related to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsiolkovsky_rocket_equation. If you don't get an answer, you could try EngineeringSE

Comment: There is some information here: http://www.coincommunity.com/forum/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=98918

Comment: This might be more engineering than physics.

Comment: Even if we identify the equations (which I'm not sure is on topic), asking their significance to the mission and spaceflight seems too broad of a questions to me.